# What's the difference between "=" and "==" for conda package versioning?

Tags: python, version, conda

For example, is there any difference between `alembic=1.4.2` and `alembic==1.4.2`? What about `pyyaml=5.4` and `pyyaml==5.4`?

And if there isn't, what's the preferred way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Conda docs:

> The fuzzy constraint numpy=1.11 matches 1.11, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.18, and so on.
>
> The exact constraint numpy==1.11 matches 1.11, 1.11.0, 1.11.0.0, and so on.

[**Source**](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#examples)